# Prevent user inputting characters not in regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field called `exampleInput`. I want the user only can write these two:

```
var pattern = /[A-Za-z][0-9]{7}[A-Za-z0-9]/;
var pattern2 = /^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i;
```

If they try to write a number or a string which does not match the patterns, stop the character from being shown. How can Ido that?

Comment: Yes, how could i prevent this?

Comment: The problem here is that you can cancel a keypress no problem, but when the user starts typing it wont (yet) match either of the regexes. So you'll need all intermediate regexes that are valid, not just the final states

Comment: @StephanBauer well spotted, I missed that

Comment: I can't understand you

Answer (score 1):

You need to break it down into multiple patterns and check all possible states.
Your first pattern has no start or end, not sure if that's what you want?
In my example I'll go with `pattern = /^[A-Za-z][0-9]{7}[A-Za-z0-9]$/`
We can check for first letter and numbers in `p0 = /^[A-Za-z][0-9]{0,7}$/`
And then we have it all set, if value does not follow `p0` nor `pattern`, block it.
You can surely do more advanced regex but readability drops **fast**.

```js
    document.getElementById('exampleInput').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (["Backspace","Delete","Enter","ArrowLeft","ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.key) >= 0) { return; }
        var value = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.selectionStart) + e.key + e.target.value.substring(e.target.selectionEnd);
        var pattern = /^[A-Za-z][0-9]{7}[A-Za-z0-9]$/;
        var p0 = /^[A-Za-z][0-9]{0,7}$/
        if (!p0.test(value) && !pattern.test(value)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
```

```html
<input id="exampleInput">
```

Comment: I don't think this code really captures the full requirement - not to mention going completely wrong when you place the cursor somewhere other than the end of the input

Comment: @Jamiec not sure about the requirements, pattern2 is subset of pattern1 so it works if i'm not missing something. Fixed the cursor thing...

Comment: pattern2 said that if it started X,Y or Z then the last character must be from a certain set. pattern1 said the last character could be any alphanumeric. Youve ony covered as far as the 7 numeric values in the middle of both patterns

Comment: @Jamiec pattern1 does not exclude X-Z so we can't assume pattern2 if input starts with X,Y,Z.

Comment: Agreed, which is why If I type `X1234567` the next character shouldnt be an `I` or `O` but your code lets me write that (This assumes pattern2 superceeds pattern1 of course which the OP didnt make clear)